# Using a function in two different ways

Tags: javascript, function

I'm creating a function that attaches to other functions.

Like:

```
string("Hi").capitilize()//returns hi
```

I want to be able to use $$.string in two different ways. 1 is attaching it to functions. The 2nd one is the function alone:

```
string("Hi")
```

That is suppose to just return Hi. But all i'm getting is: `[object Object]`

The main code that allows me to do the first one, to attach to functions is:

```
var g = function (a) { 
        this._string = typeof a == "string" ? a : a.toString();
        return a;
}
var string = function (a) {
            return new g(a);
}
```

Then I have another variable with all of the functions in it and then bind it with prototype.

Is it possible to make this just return the string if I just have string("Hi") and still allow the functions to work if you add them?

Comment: Is this code supposed to be just an example?  Because there already is a `String()` function that's kind-of similar to what you've got.

Comment: Yes just an example, my actually function is a little different (name wise)

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that a function can't tell where it's return value is headed. The call your function is over by the time that the `.` operator is being evaluated, and therefore your code can't make anything happen at that point.

Now, what you can do is return an object that's got a `toString()` implementation on its prototype, so that when your object is used in a situation where it'll be treated as a string it'll convert appropriately.

```
var g = function (a) { 
        this._string = typeof a == "string" ? a : a.toString();
        return a;
}
g.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this._string;
}
var string = function (a) {
            return new g(a);
}
alert( new string("Hi") );
```

Comment: I know, but there must be a way to do that I want. :/

Comment: @Shawn31313 though I'm sure Mr. Eich was thinking very hard about all the things that make you happy, he's only human and he may have missed something.

Comment: @Shawn31313 You know you can't do what you want, but there must be a way to do what you want?

Comment: No, i mean there must me a way to do what I want. Never said u can't do it.

Comment: @Shawn31313 there is not a way to do what you want.